# Create multidimensional associative array from a string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create multidimensional associative array from a string. Creating an array from a variable containing a string don't work. (Tested with PHP 7.1.13)

**Example that works:**

```
$myVar = array('Projets associatifs'=>['29'=>'Projet 1','15'=>'Projet 2','28'=>'Projet 3'],
               'Projets éducatifs'=>  ['10'=>'Projet 4','33'=>'Projet 5','34'=>'Projet 6']);
print_r($myVar);
```

Returns good result:

```
Array
(
  [Projets associatifs] => Array
    (
        [29] => Projet 1
        [15] => Projet 2
        [28] => Projet 3
    )
  [Projets éducatifs] => Array
    (
        [10] => Projet 4
        [33] => Projet 5
        [34] => Projet 6
    )
)
```

**Example that doesn't work:**

```
$myVar2 = "'Projets associatifs'=>['29'=>'Projet 1','15'=>'Projet 2','28'=>'Projet 3'],'Projets éducatifs'=>['10'=>'Projet 4','33'=>'Projet 5','34'=>'Projet 6']";
$myVar3 = array($myVar2);
print_r($myVar3);
```

Returns bad result:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 'Projets associatifs'=>['29'=>'Projet 1','15'=>'Projet 2','28'=>'Projet 3'],'Projets éducatifs'=>['10'=>'Projet 4','33'=>'Projet 5','34'=>'Projet 6']
)
```

What to do to make my string variable `$myVar2` accepted for creating an array?

Comment: `Creating an array from a variable containing a string don't work` that's sort of the expected behaviour, PHP dosn't magic strings into arrays, even if they look like arrays.

Comment: Ok. As there are serialize and unserialize methods, I thought we could force a properly formed string to become an array.

Comment: I can write a parser for you for it, but I don't have time right now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it's a valid array definition in PHP you can `eval` it as PHP code:

```
eval("\$myVar3 = array($myVar2);");
print_r($myVar3);
```

Or transform it into JSON and decode it.  Might be easier but I got this to work:

```
$myVar2 = str_replace(["'", '=>', '[', ']'], ['"', ':', '{', '}'], $myVar2);
$myVar3 = json_decode('{'.$myVar2.'}', true);
print_r($myVar3);
```

But if you are creating/storing this, then you would be better off just storing JSON in the fist place.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: Uhhh why? I could write my own JSON or HTML parser but there's already tools for that.

Comment: Because it's fun... I enjoy making them.  I have a method to it though.  I have a few examples on [github](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers)  Like a Html minifier I made.  I actually made a JSON one, but it's for JSON objects, basically unquoted JSON keys.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: eval("\$myVar3 = array($myVar2);"); works well and seems to be the more easy way.

Comment: @cyrcle - `eval` also comes with huge security concerns, because it will also execute any valid php that is given to it as a string.  So if there is any chance end user input could get put in it, I would not use `eval`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: In my case, the variable don't contain user input. The variable only contains a sitemap for a navigation menu. I think that in this case I can safely use `eval`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that without some crazy regex to parse the string. If you could convert the string into json, that could work.

So this
"'Projets associatifs'=>['29'=>'Projet 1','15'=>'Projet 2','28'=>'Projet 3'],'Projets éducatifs'=>['10'=>'Projet 4','33'=>'Projet 5','34'=>'Projet 6']";

Would become something like this.

{Projets associatifs: {29: 'Projet 1'}, {15:'Projet 2'}}

I didn't test this, so you'd need to figure out how to write the json to meet your needs, but then you could run that string through [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) and it will create the structure you're looking for.

Just be mindful that json works with objects. So you'd get objects back from json_decode that you would need to then convert to associative arrays if objects don't work.

However, if you find yourself doing silly stuff like this, you should reevaluate what you're trying to do and maybe find another path to your solution.

Comment: Regex alone is probably not enough, you have to write a tokenizer to handle the nesting.  Regex fails pretty baddy when it comes to nested data.  Here is an example of one I did that handles JSON objects, basically JSON with the `"`   https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/JasonDecoder.php  If I had time I would write one for them.

Comment: @Halfstop: This is an option that I have considered even if it seems odd. So, I just tested it. With json_decode($var,$assoc = TRUE) to convert returned objects into associative arrays. It works perfectly for my example.